# How to find a directed graph has a $d$ length walk between each pair of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

$G=(V,E)$  where $|V|=n$

The outdegree and indegree of each vertice is set to 2. It may contains self-loops.

Let $d=\lceil\log_2(n)\rceil$. Start with any vertice, we hope to reach all vertices (including itself) in exact $d$ steps; in other words, there's a $d$ length walk between each pair of vertices.

I can only find such graph when $n=4,5,6$. Is it possible to find such graph with larger $n$, like 8 or 16?

Finding such graph or proving it's impossible would both help. Or is it related to some well studied problem in graph theory? Thanks a lot!

[image: This is the one I find when $n=4$ and $d=2$]

Comment: Presumably by "path" you are allowing repetition of vertices (also often called a "walk")?

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I sensed "path" might be incorrect, but I didn't know the correct term. I'll see if I can fix this.

Comment: No some people do use path to allow repeated vertices, but I think that's becoming less common.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples for $n = 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13$.

```
v:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
e1: 0 1 3 2 5 6 7 4
e2: 4 6 5 7 3 1 2 0
```

```
v:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
e1: 0 1 3 2 5 6 7 4 8
e2: 4 2 0 5 7 8 3 1 6
```

```
v:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
e1: 0 1 3 2 5 6 7 4 9 8
e2: 4 2 0 6 8 1 9 3 7 5
```

```
v:  0 1 2 3 4 5  6 7 8  9 10
e1: 0 1 3 2 5 6  7 4 9 10  8
e2: 4 2 5 0 1 8 10 3 6  9  7
```

```
v:  0 1 2 3 4 5  6 7  8  9 10 11
e1: 0 1 3 2 5 6  7 4  9 10 11  8
e2: 4 2 5 0 1 8 10 3 11  6  9  7
```

```
v:  0 1 2 3 4  5  6 7  8  9 10 11 12
e1: 0 1 3 2 5  6  7 4  9 10 11 12  8
e2: 4 2 8 7 1 10 12 5 11  0  9  6  3
```

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you find these iwth a computer program ?

Comment: @ManuelLafond Yes, these were calculated using a computer (esp. the second rows of edges).

Comment: It helps a lot! Could you further explain how did you find this? As your post above, "the second rows of edges were calculated using a computer", does that means you have some rules to determine the first row?

Comment: Also, the original problem I'm working on is not about graph. In the original problem, $n=8$ and $n=16$(power of 2) are the most useful cases. Considering the case for $n=16$ may takes a long time, it would be very helpful if you can share your code on this. Do your mind?  My email is "gaosi0@sina.com". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @gs478516846 It would be great if you could provide more context on this. This piece of math seems to have a lot of connections, in particular with group theory, expander graphs, pseudorandomness and others.

Comment: @dtldarek Each vertice represents one data byte. A data block contains $n$ data bytes. The graph above represents a "data-processing" function F. F is a special kind of "permulation", it leads one byte difference to exactly two different bytes. In this case, it takes at least $d$ times for one byte difference to influence the whole data block. We are actually looking for F that reaches this lower bound.

Comment: Sorry, spelling mistake. Permutation, not "permulation"